# Find and repalce text in javascript except in <b></b> in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

currently to do search and replace string in JavaScript, I am using below code:

```
var regEX = new RegExp(toFind,"gi");
var newString = oldString.replace(regEx,toReplace);
```

where OldString contains tons of HTML tags.

What I need to do is during the execution of replace function I **don't** want the search and replace to be done on text between `<b></b>` tags.

How can I do this in Js? Is there any other way of doing the replacement?

As a example please consider below string:

```html
<div id="testDiv">
            <h2>In on announcing if of comparison pianoforte projection</h2>
            <p>Compliment interested discretion estimating on stimulated apartments oh. Dear so sing when in find read of call. As distrusts behaviour abilities defective is. Never at water me might. On formed merits hunted unable merely by mr whence or. Possession the unpleasing simplicity her uncommonly.</p>
            <b>Kept in sent gave feel will oh it we. Has pleasure procured men laughing shutters nay. Old insipidity motionless continuing law shy partiality. Depending acuteness dependent eat use dejection. Unpleasing astonished discovered not nor shy. Morning hearted now met yet beloved evening. Has and upon his last here must.</b>
            <p>New the her nor case that lady paid read. Invitation friendship travelling eat everything the out two. Shy you who scarcely expenses debating hastened resolved. Always polite moment on is warmth spirit it to hearts. Downs those still witty an balls so chief so. Moment an little remain no up lively no. Way brought may off our regular country towards adapted cheered.</p>
            <p><b>Not To be Replaced</b>Am no an listening depending up believing. Enough around remove to barton agreed regret in or it. Advantage mr estimable be commanded provision. Year well shot deny shew come now had. Shall downs stand marry taken his for out. Do related mr account brandon an up. Wrong for never ready ham these witty him. Our compass see age uncivil matters weather forbade her minutes. Ready how but truth son new under.</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: `between tags` is ambiguous .... don't touch readable content text or don't touch attributes?

Comment: Throughout whole document or just specific content sections?

Comment: @charlietfl the old String is pulled out from a specific section. But how does that matter?

Comment: can matter quite a bit if you replace innerHTML of document or parts of document you lose all the externally applied event listeners ... or deal with smaller sections just target text nodes and not have to deal with `innerHTML` and break events code

Comment: @charlietfl ... Aahh... you are rigth. No the string I am talking about is purely used for display purpose only from a specific section. So can you suggest how do I exclude contents in <b> tags from being replaced?

Comment: Would help if you provided sample html involved

Comment: The classic approach to doing this is `str.replace(/<b>.*?<\/b>|(.*)/g, function(match) { return match.replace(/oo/g, 'xx'); })`.

Answer (score -2):

I think, this is what you are looking for:

```
    var re = /[^<b>]*[^<\/b>]/gi;
    var str = '<b>Heloo..!,</b>Mr.Its<b>too hot</b>.oops!'
    var rstr = str.replace(re,'nooo');
    console.log(rstr);// prints <b>nooo</b>nooo<b>nooo</b>nooo
```

Comment: OP don't want the search and replace to be done on text between <b></b> tags

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the meaning of `[^<b>]`.

Comment: @torazaburo Can you provide some explanation.. any doc is greatful.

Comment: @Vk. I didn't see that don't.

Comment: @RamaRaoM your code produces following result when replaced with empty string: <><><>bbbb<>b<>bbb<><>bbbbbbbb<>

Comment: @PratikGaikwad Sorry, I thought that the question was to replace the text b/w <b> & </b> tags. Din't see *don't*

Comment: `[^<b>]` is a **negated character set**, which will match any character other than `<`, `b`, and `>`. This is pretty well documented in any basic description of regexp in JS, including the MDN page.

Comment: @torazaburo well in this case, its not working for some reason.